# Javascript Image Sync

Tags: javascript, html, image

If an image is already loaded in the DOM (using an  tag) before a script is ran, are either of the comments true?

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){}
image.src = "already-loaded-earlier.png";

// image.onload is guaranteed to be called right now
// image is guaranteed to be loaded and available for use right now
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Image `onload` callback always called asynchronously. If image is already loaded, `onload` is called on the next tick. The snippet below outputs `image is loaded second time` line after the `end` line.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  console.log('image is loaded first time');
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = function() {
    console.log('image is loaded second time');
  };
  img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt4Tq.jpg?s=32&g=1';
  console.log('end');

  // you can use img, without waiting `onload` to be called
  console.log(img.width, img.height);
};
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt4Tq.jpg?s=32&g=1';
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Assuming that the image is already loaded elsewhere, will it be available to use as soon as the img.src is set or is that also on the next tick?

Comment: Do you mean whether we can use image right after setting src on image object? Yes, this can be easily checked by `console.log(img.width, img.height)`. I've updated my answer.